# Full-time job after an internship (if graduating next year)

Tags: job-offer, internship

I am going into my second and final year of my graduate program. I am currently halfway through my internship, and I've really come to love the organization and the possibilities the position entails.

I've been performing well, getting constant feedback from my manager, and facilitating various meetings, all while meeting a great deal of other people. It would be a dream come true if I could come back to the organization after my internship, but I don't know how to handle the process of obtaining a full-time position if I am graduating next year.

How do I go about asking for a full-time position in a professional and appropriate way?

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your manager about it.

Tell him everything you just told us, only he can tell you if they are in a position to hire. Some places only take on interns for cheap/free work, other companies really want to hire all of their interns if they work out.

Only the manager will know the answer about your next steps for getting hired there.

---

As for how to approach this, send an email to your manager and tell him you want to talk about your current performance and possible future at this company. When you have the meeting, tell him all of the stuff you have told us. Ask the manager if there are any positions in the company that you would qualify for after graduation. You will get one of the following answers:

- We would love to hire you, here's what to do.
- We will not be filling your position after your term is complete, we will just get another intern, or leave the position vacant.
- We don't think you are quite ready yet. You are performing as expected for an intern, but not at a level we would consider for the company at this time.

No matter what the response is, it will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: SaggingRufus, thanks for your response. How would I approach the subject in an "appropriate" way? Or, what's the best way for me to bring this up?

Comment: Edited my answer to include how to approach it

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a meeting with my manager later today. I'll bring it up and see what happens!